# Three vector subspaces and their relationship.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say $U, W_1, W_2$ are subspaces of vector space $V$. Determine if following statements are true:

a) $U+W_1=U+W_2 \Rightarrow  W_1=W_2$

b) $U \oplus W_1=V=U \oplus W_2 \Rightarrow  W_1=W_2$

To be quite honest, i don't really know how could i prove this mathematically, anyway, i can see that in the case b) it is very likely that it is true because we have a direct sum, meaning that every vector in that sum can be represented as a sum of vectors from the $U$ and $W_1$ and that representation is UNIQUE, same thing works for $U$ and $W_2$ but that still ain't proof. Any help appreciated!

Comment: For $V=\Bbb{R}^2$, take $U$ as $x$-axis, $W_1$ as $y$ axis and $W_2=\text{span}\;(1,1)$

Comment: @LearningMathematics I was about to type that exact same answer. Maybe you could make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For $V=\Bbb{R}^2$, take $U$ as $x$-axis, $W_1$ as $y$ axis and $W_2=\text{span}\;(1,1)$ and see what will happen!

Comment: Ok, first statement is false since $U+W_1=span[(1,0),(0.1)]=\mathbb{R}^2$ is equal to $U+W_2=span[(1,0),(1.1)]=\mathbb{R}^2$  but $W_1$ and $W_2$ obviously are not equal. Similarly second one is false too! I appreciate your help but i am wondering is there any different approach to this other than finding counter-example? I would hardly remember that i could use counter example to prove this, because in order to use this, one should suspect that both statements are false, which i failed to do.